# Windows update failed to install driver for HD 4000 in Windows 10

Tags: drivers, bsod, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, intel-graphics

- I did an upgrade install to Windows 10 from Windows 8 (not 8.1)
- I'm getting occasional bluescreens from igdkmd64.sys (best guess is HD 4000 driver)
- Windows update tried to update the drivers twice but it says "Failed to install" in my update history
- Intel doesn't have it anywhere I can find for manual install, [their site references Windows Update for the download](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25027/Intel-Iris-Iris-Pro-and-HD-Graphics-Beta-Driver-for-Windows-10)
- I attempted to uninstall the drivers (and delete driver software checkbox), on restart it bluescreens every time
- I hope it's unrelated, but I have a thunderbolt motherboard plugged into a thunderbolt display

I want to update my driver but don't know how, it says I'm on 10.18.10.4252, I don't know the latest driver version number.

Edit: I'm also getting USB device malfunctioned notifications. The only USB devices I have are a mouse and keyboard, both still working, and the hub inside the thunderbolt display.

Comment: How did you do an upgrade installation from Windows 8.0 to Windows 10 if one of the requirements to perform that upgrade, and keep your installed applications, personal files, and application settings is that you must be running Windows 8.1 Update 1

Comment: I had no problems finding the production drivers for the [Intel HD 4000](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25150/Intel-Iris-Iris-Pro-and-HD-Graphics-Production-Driver-for-Windows-10-64-bit) on Intel's website.

Comment: I don't know why you think that. I updated using the media creation tool.

Comment: That would be great if I had 4th gen or newer, HD 4000 is 3rd gen and not supported by the driver in that link.

Comment: Considering Intel's drivers don't really work that is debatable.  Based on what I can tell Intel has not released an update to its drivers for the HD 4000.  They barely did it for the HD 4600+ if it matters, they still don't have a 32-bit product driver on their website, and its been over a week.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem.  If you are getting USB malfunction notifications, that indicates the lack of a compatible driver, is conflicting with your use of a thunderbolt display.  Sadly my suggestion is to migrate back to Windows 8, perform the Windows 8.1 upgrade, install all updates to Windows 8.1 then before you upgrade to Windows 10 uninstall your display driver with your external display disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I have three recommendations:

1. You can try downloading the Windows Update driver manually from [Windows Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Home.aspx). Unfortunately, you must do so with Internet Explorer! <s>And more unfortunately, it is not responding at this time. I hope Microsoft is not discontinuing it, just as it has discontinued the good old Windows Update client.</s> Update: Sorry pal; bad news: The latest driver available on Catalog is v10.18.10.4252. But keep checking.
2. [You can try Intel's own automatic detection and update tool](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/detect.htm).
3. If you can't find the exact driver on Intel website, use the best driver you can find there, i.e. the one for Windows 8.1.

**Be watchful:** Intel driver packages may show two or three conflicting version numbers. One is the package version number. The other is the video driver version number. The third is the audio driver version number. For example, my video driver version number is 9.17.10.4229. This number shows up on Device Manager. The package that installed this driver, however, was v15.22.54.2622. It contained audio driver 6.14.0.3097 too. The worst part is: Intel employees are also confused by all this. So, please be sure to read the readme file.

Comment: So which package from the Catalog does he get exactly?  The driver isn't going to be downloaded by the update tool, Intel only is publishing it through Windows Update, the author's entire problem is that he has the old driver still installed

Comment: @TechnoCore - `10.18.10.4226` is the last version released for Windows 8.1/Windows 8/Windows 7 per the Readme on Intel's website.